# script manager with timepicker

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I want to show this div after the user clicks on the calender component. Here, a javascript function is called to show this but the div content does not appear on calender

Without this script manager tag and time selector tag it will appear correctly.

Any help please?

```
    <div class="event" id="eventWindow" style="display: none; width: 400px; height: 250px">

        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Event Time" style="z-index: 1; left: 38px; top: 13px; position: absolute; height: 18px; width: 116px;"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> 

         <cc1:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 37px; top: 31px; position: absolute; height: 40px; width: 124px" DisplaySeconds="False">
        </cc1:TimeSelector>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter Event"></asp:Label>
        <br />
```

Java script calling.......

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string day = Convert.ToString(Calendar1.SelectedDate);
        string  [] date = day.Split(' ');

        var events = from cal in db.CalenderEvents
                     where cal.eventDate == date[0]
                     select cal.eventDescription;


        if (events.Count() == 0)
        {
            string js = @"document.getElementById('eventWindow').style.display = 'block'";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Calendar1,this.GetType(), "myalert", js, true);          


        }

}
```

Comment: In which event are you calling the JavaScript function and is it in an external .js file? Can you update your question with JS reference and it's code? And, your DIV does not have a end tag so even the time picker is not visible initially since you have the style display: none in the DIV. I hope this is not intended.

Comment: If your DIV tag had an end tag just before Label4 and some content the following JavaScript onClick of TimeSelector works fine. onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('eventWindow').style.display = '';"

Comment: i update it with java script calling.........help me...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand what you are trying to do here. You just need to add an event for each day that you select from the Calendar if there's no event for that day. If I'm correct what you are doing is wrong. You are just registering a piece of JS code but you never attach it to an event like onClick or onLoad. So my suggestion is as follows.

1. Make you DIV (eventWindow) a server side control by adding `runat="server"`
2. Instead of registering a JS code use Visible property of your DIV to make it visible (remove `display: none;` from this DIV's style property)

here's a working sample

**Marckup Code**

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> 
    <div class="event" id="eventWindow" style="width: 400px; height: 250px" runat="server"> 
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Event Time" style="z-index: 1; left: 38px; top: 13px; height: 18px; width: 116px;"></asp:Label>
        <br />       
         <cc1:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 37px; top: 31px; height: 40px; width: 124px" DisplaySeconds="False">
        </cc1:TimeSelector>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter Event"></asp:Label>
        <br />
    </div>
```

NOTE: I've removed position attributes from your style properties since the controls were displaying on top of the Calendar control.

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string day = Convert.ToString(Calendar1.SelectedDate);
        string[] date = day.Split(' ');

        var events = from cal in db.CalenderEvents
                     where cal.eventDate == date[0]
                     select cal.eventDescription;


        if (events.Count() == 0)
        {
            //string js = @"document.getElementById('eventWindow').style.display = 'block'";
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Calendar1, this.GetType(), "myalert", js, true);

            eventWindow.Visible = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you update your question with the full marckup and code behind code?